# How to get the url to edit without sending any resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, path

I would like to get the path name of an edit without sending any resource.

I can't use this

```
team_path(@team) > 'team/1234'
```

Something like this would help me to avoid the string only variant.

```
team_path_name > 'team'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is I think you need to create another routes that handle post request

```
POST /edit_team
```

So instead of using the RESTFUl routes you create another routes using post request that send using form submit that send a hidden field that consist of team id